# How to set border-radius to button in Native Script?

Tags: android, ios, xml, nativescript

I have a button:

```
<Button text="TodoSomething" cssClass="button" tap="signIn"/>
```

platform.android.css

```
.button{
-webkit-border-radius: 80px;
-moz-border-radius: 80px;
border-radius: 80px;}
```

But `border-radius` doesn't work. At [Supported Properties](http://docs.nativescript.org/styling#supported-properties) written that Native Script support `border-radius`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<Button cssClass="myclass" />

.myclass {
  border-radius: 80;
}
```

Is the way to do it. However, please note that there's currently a bug which makes radius not work on certain devices. See: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/830

Example of rounded buttons: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/apps/ui-tests-app/image-view/rounded-buttons.xml

#### Also:

In your example you're writing CSS. The language to style NativeScript applications is **not** CSS but rather a language of its own. However, as CSS is something that many people understand it borrows *very* heavily from it. But what this means is that e.g.:

- You can **not** use size definitions such as `px`, `em`, etc. The size format in NativeScript (and pretty much all Mobile development) is [DIPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_independent_pixel) and you don't specify that. Therefor you want to write: `border-radius: 80` and not `border-radius: 80px`. This is not css.
- You can't write stuff like `-webkit-border-radius: 80px;`, it's simply invalid. The NativeScript "css" is not rendered in a WebKit browser but rather converted into something iOS/Android understands.